# Can context.Context variables be copied and still function normally in all ways in golang?

Tags: go

I'm seeing the following situation:

```
func foo(ctx context.Context) {
    localCtx := ctx 
    ... //do stuff
}
```

Can both of these `context.Context` variables be used interchangeably in all ways?

Looking at the source I see that the returned `context.Context` variables from `WithCancel`, `WithDeadline`, `WithTimeout`, and `WithValue` returned are implemented internally by a pointers to structs, which would make me think that yes, they could be used interchangeably if the parent context came from one of these functions. However, the `emptyCtx` returned by `context.Background()` is an int internally, so here I'm thinking perhaps they could not be used internally if the parent context was the background context.

But `context.Context` is actually an interface and I'm not sure if/how that changes things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use them interchangeably.

As you already noticed, the `context` variables returned by `WithCancel`, etc, are actually pointers, so both `localCtx` and `ctx` will be pointing to the same thing.

About `emptyCtx` being an `int`, it should not change things as it is also being used as a pointer.

The `background` variable you mention is actually a pointer to an `emptyCtx`, as it is initialized by using the `new` keyword:

```
background = new(emptyCtx)
```

Comment: Ok, I missed the new keyword which I see in https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new returns `*Type`

Answer (score -1):

`context.Context` is an interface. Its size is two pointers. Copying up to 16 bytes is not scary at all